# How to Deal with the Logger File Size Properly in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7, operating-system

I am using following code to log

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=os.environ['USERPROFILE']+'\\myApp', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - [Thread-%(thread)d] - [Process-%(process)d] - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
```

With this logging haw can we implement the FileSize limit of logger files, like if the log file size is more than 5MB then I want to write it in new file.

In Java, we can mention the file Size like below in logback.xml

```
 <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
  <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
 </triggeringPolicy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`RotatingFileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler). This takes `maxBytes` and `backupCount` keyword parameters. From the docs:

> You can use the `maxBytes` and `backupCount` values to allow the file to
>   rollover at a predetermined size. When the size is about to be
>   exceeded, the file is closed and a new file is silently opened for
>   output. Rollover occurs whenever the current log file is nearly
>   `maxBytes` in length; if `maxBytes` is zero, rollover never occurs. If
>   `backupCount` is non-zero, the system will save old log files by
>   appending the extensions ‘.1’, ‘.2’ etc., to the filename. For
>   example, with a `backupCount` of 5 and a base file name of app.log, you
>   would get app.log, app.log.1, app.log.2, up to app.log.5. The file
>   being written to is always app.log. When this file is filled, it is
>   closed and renamed to app.log.1, and if files app.log.1, app.log.2,
>   etc. exist, then they are renamed to app.log.2, app.log.3 etc.
>   respectively.